# finding matching node within multilevel xml in as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I've got a multilevel node structure that looks something like this

```
<node>
    <node>
        <node id="a1"></node>
        <node id="a2"></node>
    </node>

    <node>
        <node id="b1"></node>
        <node id="b2"></node>
    </node>
<node>
```

I want to do a search for the first node that matches an id.

I usually use this syntax:

```
xmldata.*.(@id == "a2")[0]
```

but it looks like it's not working for multiple nested levels. Is there a way of finding the node without looping through and archiving the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `descendants()` or E4X operator `..`.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#descendants%28%29

```
var test:XML = 
<node>
    <node id="b1"></node>
    <node id="b2"></node>
    <smth>
        <node id="b3">
            <smth>
                <node id="b4"></node>
            </smth>
        </node>
    </smth>
</node>;

var search:XMLList;

search = test.descendants("node").(attribute("id") == "b4");
trace(search.toXMLString());
// OR
search = test..node.(@id == "b4");
trace(search.toXMLString());
```

Note: use `@id` notation with caution. It will give you a reference error exception if any of nodes does not contain 'id' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't fully understand your circumstances, have you tried using an [XPath implementation](http://code.google.com/p/xpath-as3/)?